# Can't search records added by other user in MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, search, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Hello helpful internet strangers. I have created a fairly simple database for a client that has one main entry form and a search form that uses unbound text boxes for searching around 15 fields.

Details are below, but here is my problem: When I add new records and use the search form all the fields work as expected and return the correct results in the datasheet. When I sent the database to the client and they add new records, they are not returned in the search. I had them save the database with their records and send it back to me, and I confirmed that when I search for the records they added (I can see the records in the table) they are not returned in the search. If I add new records to  the copy they sent me back, my records do appear in the search.

I created the database in Access 2013 on a Windows 8 machine. The client is using Access 2010 on Windows Vista.
The field types are text, dropdown and date. The dropdowns are all based on lookup queries so they store the id number in the main info table and pull the name value from the query. All of the fields in the search query are written to allow nulls, including the date range searches. And again, all fields test out correctly on my machine when I enter the records.

I went on site and compared settings and nothing jumped out at me except the different versions. I also watched the client enter new records and she didn't do anything 'wrong' or unusual. When I try to do a save as 2007-2010 it says I am using features that won't allow for that, but for the life of me I can't think of anything like that since this is really a very straightforward design.

I'm going to do a package as executable, but am highly doubtful that will help. Any insights?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We appreciate your narrative. However, we need specifics to help troubleshoot. Please provide your search VBA or macro code that runs in your search form -OnClick or AfterUpdate event handlers, control sources/recordsorces. Most likely this is not a data or platform issue but coding logic issue in your search code. Please edit.

Comment: We are not internet strangers, we are a community; you included.

Comment: Thank you both. Parfait, the OnClick event is a run query and the search was done in Query Builder. Would it help to paste the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

A few things. Most important - always, always develop in the earliest version of Access that the system will be used with. So, you need to rebuild, using Access 2010, period. Try creating a new blank database (in 2010) and importing the objects one (or a few) at a time. Make sure the system is split. One file for the FE (forms, queries, reports, code, etc.) and one for the BE (tables only). Make sure that the Filter On Load property of all forms is set to No. If the recordsource for the form contains a where clause, make sure that the newly entered records meet the criteria for the where clause.

Comment: Thanks @AVG, I was afraid of that. When I originally started building it I was using 2010, but my laptop died and with the new one came 2013. During all the previous testing the user had no problems on the search when it was just unbound text, but then I added a lot of logic for other field types. I guess I'll see if the client can get me a loaner laptop to do the rebuild.

Comment: In the long run, you will be better off doing what most of the rest of us do. Maintain a virtual machine with each version of Office that we need. Another option, if you don't need 2013, purchase a downgrade from MS, or simply uninstall it, and install Office 2010. Note that I stated Office, not just Access. You shouldn't mix any part of Office versions.

Comment: Thanks AVG, I think? I know when I signed up they said to be open minded, but I find both of your responses condescending. With the "always, always" and "do what most of the rest of us do". Your advice is basically "Go back in time and undo what you did". I did this project as a favor to a friend. I even replied to you that I was going to get a loaner or a VMI to rebuild in the clients' environment. So I appreciate the import rules advice, but otherwise I'm put off by your tone. @Olivier opened by saying this is a community. If "Duh! You did it wrong!" is the community? Count me out.

Comment: Alice, I don't know what you expected other than advice on how to solve your problem, which I provided, emphasizing very important points. Obviously, one can't go back in time. We all make mistakes and sometimes need to undo what we have done and start over. Hopefully, you won't need to start from scratch. Whether you are doing it for profit (easily construed by use of 'client') or as a favor (actually not mentioned) is not relevant. If you want the project to work, you need to essentially do what I posted. You might find some workaround that works today, but it might not later on.